# How To Update The UI of The Individual Calendar Item In Full Calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

[image]

I would like to change the way each Calendar Item renders in this Full Calendar. Is there a way to accomplish this? I already used `renderCellContents` to update the overall Calendar Date cell. But the individual item has been a challenge.

I'm using Next.js with TypeScript and MUI v4

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks

Answer (score 0):

Well Full Calendar provides custom CSS classes for changing the style and other design requirements.

Then you can use `eventContent` to handle how the UI of the events you have added would look.